# Scraping Images using Selenium ".find_element" Not Working as Intended

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape all of the images and the titles of listings on home depot starting with bolts.
Please help me get all of the images, thanks.

I have written the following code but am only getting a single image:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://www.homedepot.com/b/Hardware-Fasteners-Bolts/N-5yc1vZc26w"
driver.get(url)
images_saree = []

elements = [driver.find_element("xpath", "//img[contains(@class,'stretchy')]")]
for i in elements:
    image = i.get_attribute('src')
    images_saree.append(image)

for img in images_saree:
    file_name = img.split('/')[-1]
    print(f"HomeDepot: {file_name}")
    r = requests.get(img, stream=True)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r:
                f.write(chunk)
                
    else:
        print('')
```